# Logistic regression assumptions, linearity of continuous variables with the log odds with interaction

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, interaction

I am running a logistic regression model and I am aware of how to test the linearity assumption of continuous variables with the log odds. However, I am not sure if this has to be checked in the presence of an interaction term. For example if I model a continuous and categorical variable as well as their interaction, and the continuous variable fails the linearity assumption, it should still be okay to include the interaction term, is this correct? Or do I need to check linearity of the continuous variable at each level of the categorical variable?

Say for example a continuous 'time' variable is not linearly related with the log odds, but at different levels (for example 'gender') this interaction is significant in the full model. It would seem that excluding time, and thus the interaction term because it violates the linearity assumption, would not be good practice and result in a poor model.

I'd appreciate a potential reference if someone knows the answer.

Comment: If linearity exist between a subgroup of your data and not in other groups, you can fit the model because this is what you are trying to infer, whether a relationship exist between your dependent and independent variable.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, would one way to deal with non-linearity of a continuous variable be to make an interaction term with it and another variable of interest? (assuming there is reason to believe the two variables interact on the dep var?)

Comment: it's not so much of dealing with it or trying to make the data fit. If you are including an interaction term that doesn't make sense, in terms of what you are trying to model, then how would this help you?

Comment: Or maybe you should make this less vague and actually describe the purpose of your regression or analysis

Comment: say the purpose of the regression is to see whether age, gender, or the interaction of age and gender influence whether someone dies. it is my understanding age must be linearly related to the log odds. If this assumption fails, I am not sure what I do with my age variable, or the interaction variable. perhaps I misunderstand the linearity assumption, in which case feedback would be appreciated

Comment: yes in this case it's ok if you see that there is a relationship for one gender and not for the other. If you fit the model you are not violating anything

Comment: Separate the data by gender. Draw two scatterplots, one for each gender, and superimpose the loess smooths on each. Then post the graphs so we can all see what you really have.